# How to deal with Question Mark in regular expression in nginx cofig file

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to nginx environment. May i know how to deal with question mark , arguments and values from the URL in nginx.
Below are the requests that nginx config file receives.
http://example.com/api/student?id=123,
http://example.com/api/student?name=yuva1,
http://example.com/api/student?place=KL,     http://example.com/api/student?marks=56 .

The values after "=" (equal to) symbol can be anything. id may get 456 and name may receive jam5 etc.,
Let me know how to deal with this in nginx config file. Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to do?

Comment: @TanHongTat These requests need to be handled by nginx config

Answer (score 0):

Nginx embedded variables will provide the value for the parameter.

For example,

http://example.com/api/student?id=123

$arg_id = 123

> $arg_name
>
> ```
> argument name in the request line
> ```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: Its done with $query_string parameter. Thanks for your help!!